# Datagrid Rails : Hide header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datagrid

I'm using the datagrid gem with Rails 4 (https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid) and I'd like to hide the header for csv generation

How can I skip the header generation in the csv files ?

Comment: What's the way to skip the header generation in the csv files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the datagrid gem myself, but looking at the source code, the [`to_csv` method](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/blob/a68092625f574aaa2eb1a7237eb49558c3b2e72f/lib/datagrid/columns.rb#L315-L325) specifies writing the headers as a default:

```
CSV.generate(
  {:headers => self.header(*column_names), :write_headers => true}.merge!(options)
) do |csv|
```

The act of `.merge!(options)` will be to overwrite those defaults. So, if you call `grid.to_csv(:write_headers => false)` from your own code, you shouldn't get any headers.

For more information about what options you can pass here, you should look at the standard library documentation for the CSV module [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new).